# Symfony2 - Propel and KnpPaginatorBundle: how to sort by column?

Tags: symfony, propel

In a Symfony2 project using Propel ORM, I am trying to sort a list view by column, using KNP Paginator bundle. My code is the following:

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    $query = CustomerQuery::create();

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1), 30);

    return compact('pagination');
}
```

And my view is:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ pagination.sortable('Company', 'companyName')|raw }}</th>
            <th>{{ pagination.sortable('Contact', 'contact')|raw }}</th>
            <th>{{ pagination.sortable('E-mail', 'email')|raw }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for customer in pagination %}
            <!-- [...] -->
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The generated links seems to be correct, as I got (for instance):

> /customers/?sort=companyName&direction=asc&page=1

But it does not sort my query: there is no *ORDER BY* clause in my generated request. So, my question is: is result ordering available for Propel (and if so, where am I wrong)? Or should I deal it manually in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subscriber to the *knp_paginator.subscriber* event and make it a class that apply some sort on the query.

Take example on the *Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Sortable\Doctrine\ORM\QuerySubscriber*.

I'll make a PR to the knp_components to add a PropelQuerySortable class but I don't know when exactly.